# Adding UserNotifications.framework causes codesign -1 error (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'll start with just the error,

```
   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <keyremoved> --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none /Users/charlesgeorge/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cvqmwrcjxssykmdqdwkfdmzbtrxc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Lucktastic.app/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework

/Users/charlesgeorge/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cvqmwrcjxssykmdqdwkfdmzbtrxc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Lucktastic.app/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

This only occurs on Archive.  Running on my phone loads correctly.

Things I've tried so far.

1. Delete Derived Data, clean, clean build-> same issue
2. Changing to managed provisioning

Nada

The culprit seems to be UserNotifications.framework.

If I set it as a linked framework, it will build, but when I run it on iOS I get an error on iOS9.  I've embedded the binary instead, and that gets things to run okay, but that starts the codesigning issues.  This is the setup

http://screencast.com/t/89eoG82gdjW

Any ideas on why that won't codesign properly, or how to link framework correctly with iOS 9?

Answer (score -1):

Okay,

After working for a while.  The issue is that I shouldn't have even been including that framework.  I just need to flip the "Uses Push Notifications" to get it working, and remove all references to the UserNotifications.framework.